# DateTime.Now culture/format on Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, datetime-format

For the sake of testing, the Web Server is on a computer with `Maori` culture where the short date format like this: `d/MM/yyyy`.

The user is on a computer with `Hungarian` culture and the short date format is `yyyy.MM.dd.`

I've created a webpage that will display DateTime.Now on a label when the page is loaded. The displayed date is `2/18/2013 2:22:06 PM`.

So now my question is, how come the displayed date is in another format/culture, which I suspect Eng-US?

Secondly, I will need to compare date from database (assuming the database is on a computer with a different culture) to DateTime.Now. To do this, I plan to convert the date from database to match the culture of the Web Server. But given the situation in my first question, how do I know in which culture/format DateTime.Now will be in?

EDIT: The code used:

```
DateTime nowDateTime = DateTime.Now;
Label7.Text = nowDateTime.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: We can't tell why a particular culture is used without seeing *anything* of your code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Actually the code is quite straightforward. I've edited my question to add the code.

Comment: I agree it's straightforward, but it's still necessary information :) I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ixora did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14931419/468718) helped you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first part of your question: your code is basically just using the current thread culture. You could either make sure that the current thread culture for each request is set to a suitable culture *for* that request (based on accept headers etc - see [`HttpRequest.UserLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx)) or you could pass that explicitly to all calls to `ToString` etc.

As for why it's coming up in US English format - that may well be the culture that the web-serving *service* is running as. That may well not be the same as the culture that the desktop uses. You should take pains to make sure that's *not* used except possibly as a fallback if the user request doesn't provide any information. (I'd be tempted to pick an explicit fallback rather than using the default for the service.)

> Secondly, I will need to compare date from database (assuming the database is on a computer with a different culture) to DateTime.Now.

Using `DateTime.Now` is almost certainly a bad idea. In most cases, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` and store UTC date/times in the database. (There are cases where you should instead store a local time and a time zone, but even then you wouldn't use `DateTime.Now`.)

> To do this, I plan to convert the date from database to match the culture of the Web Server. But given the situation in my first question, how do I know in which culture/format DateTime.Now will be in?

The culture is primarily relevant when converting to and from *string* representations. You should avoid any such conversion when either storing a value in the database or retrieving it. Instead, make sure that you're using an appropriate field type in the database (`DATETIME` or whatever) and then fetch it *as a `DateTime`* in your data access layer. If you find yourself trying to use `DateTime.Parse` or anything similar, that should ring alarm bells. You haven't told us what data access technology you're using, but pretty much everything allows you to retrieve a `DateTime` directly. (e.g. [`DbDataReader.GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime.aspx).)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I took the time to work it out based on your explanation and eventually forgot to reply. Thank you for your explanation. I checked the current thread culture and it was really En-US. Based on your explanation I managed to solve the problem. I use this format "yyyyMMdd H:mm:ss" when saving to the database. When I'm comparing the date, I convert both date into web server's format and culture before comparing them

Comment: @ixora: Why would you use any sort of format when saving to the database, or when comparing? As I tried to make really clear, you shouldn't be using a string representation at all if you can help it - convert to `DateTime` as soon as you can, and then stick to that.

Answer (score 2):

when comparing dates in different time zones it would make sense to store it in the database as UTC. Then you could easily compare it with any other date from any time zone (again converted to UTC).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I was researching for this problem I came across with this solution several time. But since the existing part of the system does not store the date in UTC, it will be inconsistent if I adopt this solution for the new part of the system. I came across this format "yyyyMMdd H:mm:ss" from a Microsoft forum (too bad I didn't bookmark it) and used it to save into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, I don't think the culture is really Maori on the relevant thread. Try this to test:

```
Label7.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
```

If it is `"mi"` or `"mi-NZ"`, it is Maori. Something with `"en"` would be English, `"hu"` Hungarian, and so on.

Note that if the current culture is changed programmatically, this affects only the current thread. Not other threads. But did you try to set the locale in the Control Panel of Windows?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did this and it says en-US. No wonder! :D I set the region at Control Panel and not programmatically but the thread's culture still turned out to be en-US. However, thanks to this piece of information, I got the idea on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How come the displayed date is in another format/culture, which I suspect Eng-US?

Answer: `DateTime.Now` which renders `2/18/2013 2:22:06 PM` on a label is <strike>already</strike> in <strike>`Maori`</strike>English culture which may be due to current web server configurations or it is picking user's request culture.

Possible solution:
**To render it in client's culture i.e. Hungarian Culture**

1. Easiest and Framework Handles, Modify the configuration to adapt to user's Request Headers
2. Manual and you need to code for this, You need to handle `Page`'s `InitializeCulture` event and change `Culture` for the executing `HttpRequest` based on user's request Header `Accept-Language` which should be something like `Accept-Language: hu-HU,en;q=0.8`

Code Sample for 1 point above

```xml
<system.web>
       <globalization
                  enableclientbasedculture="true"
                  uiculture="auto"
                  culture="auto">
       </globalization>
</system.web>
```

For this Refer [Scott Hanselman's Post on Globalisation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) of which concept can be applied to Web Forms Applications also.

> For reading database values use code snippet as,

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("mi-NZ");
DateTime.Parse(sqlDbReader["MyDateColumnName"], culture)
```

Refer: [Format SqlDataReader as date](http://www.wallaceit.co.uk/asp-net-vb/format-sqldatareader-as-date/169/article.aspx) and [MSDN - DateTime.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for replying however the displayed date is not in Maori culture. If it was the case, then the date would have been displayed like this `18/02/2013` instead of like this `2/18/2013`. A further check reveled that the thread's culture is en-US, hence the format. Since the web application that I'm developing should be independent of Database Server's culture, Web Server's culture and User's Computer culture, I should not hard code any culture information into it. I managed to solve the problem as mentioned in my comment to Jon Skeet's reply